# In biblatex have author name listed as `Doe, J.D.` in the references (i.e. no space between initials)

Tags: spacing, biblatex

To have author names be listed as e.g. `Doe, J.D.` in the references (i.e. no space between initials). I use in my `.bbx` file:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions
  {
    firstinits = true,
    terseinits = false
}
```

But the result is `Doe, J. D.` with spaces between the initials.
I tried adding `\renewcommand\bibinitdelim{\nospace}` to the `.bbx` file but that gives an error.

> Question: any way to suppress the space between author's name initials (with or without calling `terseinits = false`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\nospace` is (at least in the LaTeX core and `biblatex`) undefined. Use an empty argument in the redefinition of `\bibinitdelim` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits=true,terseinits=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Doe, John D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {How to remove the space between initials},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd warmly suggest the alternative `\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{\,}`

Comment: @egreg [I'd, too.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10203/biblatex-putting-thin-spaces-between-initials)

Comment: hmm, that doesn't seem to work for me. (while `\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{}` works like a charm).

Comment: @RoeyAngel `\,` adds a non-breakable *thin* space.

Comment: oh that explains. But in any case that's not what my journal asks (and unfortunately I'm not in a position to make them change this).