# Harvard style bibliography with biblatex... almost, but not quite!

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

My University requires that all submissions use the Harvard format for referencing.  I understand this is not directly supported by BibLaTeX without some tweaking.

I spent much of my evening yesterday researching how to do this and I have *almost* managed to get BibLaTeX to output my bibliography in the required format.  Below is an example of the current output:

[image: Example of Harvard bibliography]

However, a few issues still remain unresolved.

1. There should be no spacing between the first and middle initials of authors, i.e. `Doe, J.D.` not `Doe, J. D.`.  I have tried using `\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{}` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82078/36988), but it did not work.  The nearest I have to a solution is to insert a thin space as suggested in [this response](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11128/36988).
2. The first author should be listed as `de Silva, U.C.`, not `Silva, U.C. de`.
3. The year of publication should not have a full stop after the parentheses, i.e. `(2011)`, not `(2011),`.
4. Some bibliography entries will need to be appended with additional information (such as the date of access, if the source was online, etc.) using the `note` field at the end of the entry.  However, the current settings cause the `note` field for articles to be sandwiched between the volume number and page numbers, rather than after the page numbers, as shown below:

[image: biblatex note field]

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can resolve these formatting issues?

Here are the settings I've applied so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
firstinits=true, % render first and middle names as initials
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=99,
style=authoryear,
dashed=false, % re-print recurring author names in bibliography
natbib=true,
url=false
]{biblatex}

% Use single quotes around titles:
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\let~\,#1}} % insert thin spaces between author initials
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} % insert a comma between author and year in-text citations
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace} % comma as separator in bibliography, not full stop
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep} % increase spacing between entries in bibliography
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % remove 'in:' preceding article title

% Place volume number within parentheses:
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
    \printfield{volume}
    \setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional); there's also \addnbthinspace
    \printfield{number}
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}
    \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Belshe_2010a,
  Title = {{{E}fficacy of live attenuated influenza vaccine in children against influenza {B} viruses by lineage and antigenic similarity}},
  Author = {Belshe, R. B. and Coelingh, K. and Ambrose, C. S. and Woo, J. C. and Wu, X.},
  Journal = {Vaccine},
  Year = {2010},
  Month = {Feb},
  Note = {[Online]. Available at: \url{example.com} (Accessed: 10 January 2013)},
  Number = {9},
  Pages = {2149--2156},
  Volume = {28},
}

@Article{de-Silva_2012,
  Title = {{{A} comprehensive analysis of reassortment in influenza {A} virus}},
  Author = {de Silva, U. C. and Tanaka, H. and Nakamura, S. and Goto, N. and Yasunaga, T.},
  Journal = {Biol Open},
  Year = {2012},
  Month = {Apr},
  Number = {4},
  Pages = {385--390},
  Volume = {1},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*} % print all citations

\begin{document}
    \printbibliography[title=References]
\end{document}
```

My setup consists of TeXstudio 2.3, TeXlive 2012, and BibLaTeX 1.7-1 on Debian Wheezy, if that affects anything.

Thanking you all in advance,

Baldwin

**EDIT:** Thanks for your helpful replies everyone.  This is the first document in which I've used the BibLaTeX package, so I really appreciate your responses.

Comment: For the space between initials, say `\def~{}` instead of `\let~\,` as in the quoted answer. (I consider it bad style to have no space between initials, but it's another matter.)

Comment: As always, 'Harvard' style simply means author-date. The exact formatting is really down to individual institutions/journals.

Comment: `biblatex` provides field dedicated to the URL (aptly named `url`) and the access date of that URL (called `urldate`), you can customise the appearance of those fields (see for example [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51194/35864)), but it might be better to use them than just whacking everything into the `note` (or `addendum` field).

Comment: You should not use `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\let~\,#1}}` (`\let`ting integral commands such as `~` is not the best option in most cases), use `\renewcommand*{\bibnamedelimd}{\addlpthinspace}` instead.

Comment: @moewe - I didn't know about the `url` and `urldate` fields, thanks for pointing those out.  I appreciate that shoving everything into the `addendum` field is a bit of a kludge, but it works well enough and I'm pushed for time, so it'll do for now.

Comment: @Baldwin You have already received an answer to your original question; if you have further problems, it's better to ask a fresh question, with a link to this one. Maybe the new problem can be tackled as an extension of the given anwswer, maybe not.

Comment: @egreg - Thank you, I've removed the further problems from my original post and asked them as new questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ad 1: `\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{}` works for me. EDIT: Note that `\bibinitdelim` requires Biber instead of BibTeX. As this command  was added in `biblatex` 1.3, there's a chance that it works with your distribution (try the `backend=biber` option); nevertheless consider to upgrade to the current versions of `biblatex` and Biber.

Ad 2: Use the package option `useprefix=true`.

Ad 3: `\usepackage{xpatch}\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\nopunct}{}{}`.

Ad 4: Use the `addendum` instead of the `note` field. EDIT: In the case at hand, follow moewe's advice and use the `url` and `urldate` fields.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
firstinits=true, % render first and middle names as initials
useprefix=true,
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=99,
style=authoryear,
dashed=false, % re-print recurring author names in bibliography
natbib=true,
url=false
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\nopunct}{}{}

% Use single quotes around titles:
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\let~\,#1}} % insert thin spaces between author initials
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} % insert a comma between author and year in-text citations
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace} % comma as separator in bibliography, not full stop
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep} % increase spacing between entries in bibliography
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % remove 'in:' preceding article title

% Place volume number within parentheses:
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
    \printfield{volume}
    \setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional); there's also \addnbthinspace
    \printfield{number}
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}
    \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Belshe_2010a,
  Title = {{{E}fficacy of live attenuated influenza vaccine in children against influenza {B} viruses by lineage and antigenic similarity}},
  Author = {Belshe, R. B. and Coelingh, K. and Ambrose, C. S. and Woo, J. C. and Wu, X.},
  Journal = {Vaccine},
  Year = {2010},
  Month = {Feb},
  Addendum = {[Online]. Available at: \url{example.com} (Accessed: 10 January 2013)},
  Number = {9},
  Pages = {2149--2156},
  Volume = {28},
}

@Article{de-Silva_2012,
  Title = {{{A} comprehensive analysis of reassortment in influenza {A} virus}},
  Author = {de Silva, U. C. and Tanaka, H. and Nakamura, S. and Goto, N. and Yasunaga, T.},
  Journal = {Biol Open},
  Year = {2012},
  Month = {Apr},
  Number = {4},
  Pages = {385--390},
  Volume = {1},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*} % print all citations

\begin{document}
    \printbibliography[title=References]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't one use `\renewcommand*{\bibnamedelimd}{\addlpthinspace}` instead of `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\let~\,#1}}`?

Comment: @moewe Indeed. I dealt with the issues raised by the OP, but didn't  peruse the other modifications.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess I better raise this issue in a comment to the question.

Comment: @moewe No problem. And nice to see that another `biblatex` adept has joined tex.sx.

Comment: @karlkoeller How can i add a ":" (colon without ") after the year in the Bibliography list followed by the title etc., For example: "Hansmann, K.-W. (2001): Industrielles Management,..........."

Comment: @lockstep How can i add a ":" (colon without ") after the year in the Bibliography list followed by the title etc., For example: "Hansmann, K.-W. (2001): Industrielles Management,..........." –