# Use non-breaking space after name initials with biblatex macros

Tags: spacing, biblatex, line-breaking

I want to enforce biber/biblatex to place non-breaking spaces between initials and last names of authors. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\person}[2]{\citename{#1}[#2]{author}}

\DeclareNameFormat{firstinits-last}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sci}{firstinits-last}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{latour,
    AUTHOR      = {Latour, Bruno},
    OPTIONS     = {dataonly=true}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar. 
\person{latour}{sci} says about the ``new object'' that emerges\ldots
\end{document}
```

This produces a line break between `B.` and `Latour`:

[image]

I have looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10203/biblatex-putting-thin-spaces-between-initials), but the suggested code doesn't have any effect here:

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\let~\,#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\iffirstinits{\let~\,}{}#1}}
```

How would I make `B. Latour` in this example be rendered as `B.~Latour` (normal non-breaking space)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are now a series of different flexible delimiters between the parts of a name (when using Biber). They are `\bibnamedelima`, to  `\bibnamedelimd` plus `\bibnamedelimi` and the marker command `\revsdnamepunct`. Their full use cases are described in the manual: basically, `\bibnamedelima`/`\bibnamedelimb` go between first names or between surnames (*i.e.* for gaps within the same 'part' of the name) while  `\bibnamedelimc`/`\bibnamedelimd` between the first name(s) and surnames (between 'parts'). `\bibnamedelimi` goes after initials in the first name part, replacing `\bibnamedelima`/`\bibnamedelimb`, when conversion to initials is active. Thus depending on the settings, either `\bibnamedelimc` or `\bibnamedelimd` applies in the current case (see the manual): it's just a question of altering the definitions

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\person}[2]{\citename{#1}[#2]{author}}

\DeclareNameFormat{firstinits-last}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sci}{firstinits-last}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{latour,
    AUTHOR      = {Latour, Bruno},
    OPTIONS     = {dataonly=true}
}
\end{filecontents}
\renewcommand*\bibnamedelimc{\addnbspace}
\renewcommand*\bibnamedelimd{\addnbspace}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar. 
\person{latour}{sci} says about the ``new object'' that emerges\ldots
\end{document}
```

I've altered both setting here, but it's `d` that applies in the current case.

Comment: You could use `\renewcommand*\bibnamedelimd{~}`: I've chosen to stick with the `biblatex` 'official' approach.

Comment: You might consider `\renewcommand*\bibnamedelimd{\addhighpenspace}`, which makes it harder to break here but not impossible (depending on the real case, it can be tricky to avoid all breaks in names, especially in the bibliography).

Comment: But `\bibnamedelimd` will affect the space after the first name whatever its shape, whether entire or abbreviated. If you want to only affect the space if the first name is automatically abbreviated, I wonder if there is a command. `\ifgiveninits` should do the job, I guess.